# CMS with support of Multilingual and custom url rewriting

Tags: drupal, plone

I'm searching a CMs that can offer me these features :

- Localized fields with a custom number of languages
- Each article belong to a category that may have parent categories
- language and category  could be calculated from url example /en/maincategory/subcategory/my-article-url-rewrite

I was looking in drupal for these features. I haven't yet found something on localization. I have found another solution that could satisfy my need which is [Plone](http://plone.org/) but I can't decide which can can give me what I want. Can Drupal do all this ? Plone ? Or there is another solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plone seems quite a good choice for this project.

- Localization can be handled using the excellent product [LinguaPlone](http://plone.org/products/linguaplone);
- Hierachical categories can be handled using [collective.virtualtreecategories](http://plone.org/products/collective.virtualtreecategories), or using hierarchical vocabularies and a custom field with a [collective.dynatree](http://plone.org/products/collective.dynatree) widget (I did something similar in a recent project);
- Plone does not retrive content using *URL dispatch*, but *path traversal*; however, using correct content placement inside folders, you can have a directory structure that complies with your format.

Of course, you will also have access to Plone's powerful User and Group management facilities, ACLs, workflow engine, and many other features.

If you are knowledgable in Python, you might also want to look at [Django](http://www.djangoproject.org), which is more like a framework than a CMS, but hey...

Comment: Plone theme engine how does it works ? And is it very flexible ?

Comment: Flexible? Definitely. There are many ways of theming your Plone site. The latest and sexiest tech is Diazo (collective.xdv): http://collective-docs.plone.org/templates_css_and_javascripts/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, eg. Drupal 6 is able to do that. Just take a closer look at modules:

- i18n (shortcut for "internationalization"),
- Locale,
- Language Icons,
- Pathauto,
- Transliteration,
- etc.

There are a lot of tools for that.

To look for multilanguage-related modules, just follow the link: http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid%3A97%20drupal_core%3A87%20bs_project_sandbox%3A0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc

Drupal even provides translation files for its interface and some modules have translation of their interface bundled in the installation files.

If you only need the features you specified, the only thing you need is to install modules you choose, change the default configuration if needed, and you are able to do what you planned :) Drupal has some administration interface that is not friendly to new users, but it is surely able to quickly fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Is that possible to apply a theme per page ?

Comment: Yes, there are modules for content publishing workflows, also themes can be altered depending on multiple factors.

When it comes to modules, there is aprox. 10 thousands of them (afair), by default accessible on http://drupal.org/project/modules

If you need reviews, you can visit httpdrupalmodules.com

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a fixed list of categories and sub-categories then all of your requirements are standard features of the eZ Publish CMS available at [http://share.ez.no](http://share.ez.no/)
If they are not a fixed-list then you may need to create a bit of custom code.
That CMS also uses [Zeta Components](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://incubator.apache.org/projects/zetacomponents.html&ei=_djCTceqHYaEhQeHsbTCBQ&usg=AFQjCNGsWcPPC6smsbQzrY7nm9modJeHGw&sig2=gQ1HwN5we0qMRRwCmYGFZg)